# How to replace line in chart by serie of dot?

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, d3.js

I'm attempting to use the ['Reusable Charts' approach](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/#examples) described by @mbostock, everything is fine when using a line (`<path>`).
However, when I try to use dots (`<circle>`), only one element is added to the chart and it's not well formed (wrong `cx` and `cy`).

My attempted code is between [lines 50-55 of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DDuH/3/).

Comment: Why is this the exact same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491586/how-can-i-made-a-dot-chart-from-d3-js-template-reusable-charts by another user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

great work on leveraging the reusable chart API!

In order to work with circles, the data needs to be bound to the collection of circles as well. There are a variety of ways you can take a look at [selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) for more information (search for array of arrays for the tricky bit that would give you some other insight on how to do it differently).

http://jsfiddle.net/7rdU7/

Above is a fix made to your example, keeping it simple and easy to understand what the differences are.

```
g.selectAll('.circle').data(data).enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "dot")
            .attr("cx", function(d) {return xScale (d.date); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {return yScale (d.ySpeed); })
            .attr("r", function(d) {return rScale (d.xSpeed); });
```

If you are looking to transition between one visualization (a line) to a set of points. This is where it becomes a very tricky game of figuring out how to create a set of varying sized circles all leveraging an `svg:path` element. If that's the case you should look at the source of the [crossfilter example](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) to see how it is done to create several varying bar charts, though I really don't know if this is the ideal way to work with it.

Comment: +1 for a nice demo, though I'm not sure it's what the OP was looking for.

Comment: See the result chrt : an historic of wind (direction/strength) > http://jsfiddle.net/2DDuH/8

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the path, change how the path is drawn.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2DDuH/5/

[image: graph using circles to display the line]

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray:0 20
}
```

By using a fatter stroke, a round line cap, and dashed lines that 'draw' for 0px followed by a gap, your path is stroked with a series of circles. Your `stroke-width` controls the diameter of your circles.

You can provide an arbitrarily complex dasharray to unevenly space them, if you want. For example, try `0 20 0 40 0 6 0 30 0 15 0 30`.

Comment: That's visually correct, but I need autonomous object so I can edit their attributes.