# How can i made a dot chart from d3.js template 'Reusable Charts'

Tags: charts, d3.js

I'm attempting to use the ['Reusable Charts' approach](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/#examples) described by @mbostock, everything is fine when using a line (`<path>`).
However, when I try to use dots (`<circle>`), only one element is added to the chart and it's not well formed (wrong `cx` and `cy`).

My attempted code is between [lines 50-55 of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DDuH/3/).
I tried to append a circle to my svg for each data but it is not added.

Comment: Why is this the exact same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490581/how-to-replace-line-in-chart-by-serie-of-dot by another user?

Comment: Indeed this one is a duplicate by my teammate, please close/delete as we accepeted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is the d3.svg.line generator takes an array as input, but a circle element only needs one value of this array. So first, you have to get the data binding right.

Next, you need to have the scales right. cx and cy can use the X and Y scale accessor functions. The radius also need a scale, because your xSpeed contains negative numbers and a radius can't be negative. So here is the fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/christopheviau/2DDuH/6/

```
var speedScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d, i){return d.xSpeed;}))).range([2, 10]);
            gEnter.selectAll('circle.dot')
                .data(function(d, i){return d})
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "dot")
                .attr("cx", X)
                .attr("cy", Y)
                .attr("r", function(d, i){return speedScale(d.xSpeed)});
```

Comment: with this I draw an historic of wind (direction/strength) chart : http://jsfiddle.net/2DDuH/8/